# Prevent user from entering additional characters when maximum length reached

Tags: javascript, forms, angularjs, validation, input

Using angularjs, I'm not satisfied with the `ng-maxlength` tag. I want the input field to block the user from entering additional characters when the max length has been hit. So instead of `ng-maxlength`, I tried writing a directive that would validate the input on keydown/keypress:

```
.directive('vldMaxLength', function() {
  return function (scope, element, attr) {
    element.bind('keydown keypress', function (event) {
      if(event.target.value.length >= 10 && (event.which !== 8 && event.which !== 46)) {
        event.preventDefault();
      }
    });
  };
})
```

This works decently, but the user is unable to highlight a portion of the string and replace with different characters. Maybe there's something I can add to the directive to allow for this? Or maybe there's an easier way to get this functionality instead of using a directive.

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/DwKZh/147/

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You could use the [straight HTML version](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_input_maxlength.asp):

```
<form action="demo_form.asp">
  Username: <input type="text" name="usrname" maxlength="10"><br>
  <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

Comment: @mila if you're using Angular, use the Angular way of limiting field length.

Comment: @ArlenBeiler ng-maxlength: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/input

it gives more information to the data model than a simple HTML solution so you can give feedback to the user, for example.